# codeigniter login with facebook getUser() return 0

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication

Well I'm trying to implement login with facebook using codeigniter I always have 0 when I call getUser() function , I tried all the possible solution but none of them works for me I don't know why , here is my facebook library class :

```
<?php 

include(APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');

class Fbconnect extends Facebook {

    public $user = NULL;
    public $user_id = FALSE;
    public $fb = FALSE;
    public $fbSession = FALSE;
    public $appkey = 0;

    public function Fbconnect(){

        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->config->load('facebook', TRUE);
        $config = $ci->config->item('facebook');        
        parent::__construct($config);
        parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );

        $this->user_id = $this->getUser();
        $me = null;
        if($this->user_id){
            try{
                $me = $this->api('/me');
                $this->user = $me;
            } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                error_log($e);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and here my main controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {

            $this->load->view('index');
    }

        public function fb_request()
        {
            $this->load->library('fbconnect');
            $data = array(
                'redirect_uri' => site_url('main/handle_facebook_login'),
                'scope' => array('email','user_birthday')
            );
            redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($data));
        }

        public function handle_facebook_login()
        {
            $this->load->library('fbconnect');
            $user = $this->fbconnect->user;
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r($user);
                echo "</pre>";
            if($user)
            {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($user);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Could not login ... ";
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This same problem gave me serious migraine..lol but what solved the problem was to include index.php both in the fb login redirect url and also in your Facebook app site url. I was using htaccess with codeigniter so didnt use the index.php in my URLs even though its being called on every page request. Maybe you should try that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you AppId and secret key are correct as per your application.some time application may take some time to get activated.

Comment: well I'm pretty sure that app setting is true ,
BTW I have this notice : 

    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Notice

    Message: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE - assumed 'CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE'

    Filename: facebook/base_facebook.php

    Line Number: 958

Comment: Please enable the curl of you server.

Comment: I use a free host from serversfree.com and I think the curl is already enabled as this page says http://www.serversfree.com/server-features/

Comment: well I choose to use php version 5.3 and the notice disappear but when I request http://eit.bugs3.com/main/fb_request
I still have 0 and 'Could not login ... '

Comment: I have also suffer from this kind of problem some point of time.its just a mistake with the facebok application configure..Just make sure all the fields in the developer.facebook.com are correct.

Comment: Well I delete the last app and create a new one I set the App Domains to eit.bugs3.com and the Site URL to http://eit.bugs3.com/
and the problem not solved , http://eit.bugs3.com/main/fb_request